# Parse String Date time in java

Tags: java

I have a date time (which is a string) in the following format: `2/19/2015 5:25:35 p.m`, and I wanted to turn it in the following Date Format: `Thu Feb 19 5:25:35 p.m. CET 2015` I tried the following code:

```
String sDatePrecedenteExecution  = "19/02/2015 17:30:29";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("ddd d mmm yyyy HH: mm: ss");
Date date = format.parse (sDatePrecedenteExecution)
```

but I got the following error:

```
java.text.ParseException: unparseable Date: "2/19/2015 5:30:29 p.m."
Has java.text.DateFormat.parse (DateFormat.java:337)
```

Comment: tell us from which package is this `Date` from? java.util ?

Comment: try this `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` as pattern for SimpleDateFormat

Comment: You give us inconsistent data: your string assignment contradicts your claim about the format of the input data.

Comment: ya the format you mentioned in question and in the one in code are different. which one do you need to parse ?

Comment: Looks like `p.m` is not effecting the pattern. So you can use the one I mentioned in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SimpleDateFormat doesn't match the format which you are entering. They should reflect the same.

Try this code

```
String parseDate = ""19/02/2015 17:30:29";

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(parseDate);
```

Comment: to retrieve the value of sDatePrecedenteExecution it took me to do  : 'this.sDatePrecedenteExecution'.

rather than sDatePrecedenteExecution and parse works                                                                                                         thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You are currently using the "output" format to read your incoming date string (`2/19/2015 5:25:35 p.m`), which is why you see the error.

You need to specify a second format for parsing your incoming date string, and use that format to parse instead. It should look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
Date date = inFormat.parse(sDatePrecedenteExecution)
```

Note that you also have a bug in your output format - `m` means minutes, and you want `MMM`, which is months. [Have a look at the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code something like...

```
    String sDatePrecedenteExecution  = "19/02/2015 17:30:29";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse (sDatePrecedenteExecution);
        System.out.println(date);
        format = new SimpleDateFormat ("ddd d mmm yyyy HH: mm: ss");
        String str = format.format(date);
        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd mm yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

You went wrong when you made: `"ddd d mmm yyyy HH: mm: ss"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss" instead & read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  String sDatePrecedenteExecution  = "19/02/2015 17:30:29";
 try{date =format.parse (sDatePrecedenteExecution);
      }catch(Exception ex){//deal with it here}
  System.out.println(date.toString()); //Thu Feb 19 17:30:29 UTC 2015
```